# Arduino долгое нажатие кнопки

Tags: arduino

Имеется код, в котором при нажатии на кнопку на СОМ порт ПК передается значение "H", а при повторном нажатии - "L". Интересует, как можно сделать еще одно событие, а именно: при нажатии на кнопку на порт передается значение "H", при нажатии еже раз  - "Р", а при удержании клавиши одну секунду на СОМ порт должен передаваться значение "L". Выкладываю имеющийся код, подскажите, пожалуйста. Если что-то будет не ясно - я объясню:

```
int switchPin = 12;
int ledPin = 13;
boolean lastBut = LOW;
boolean curBut = LOW;
boolean ledOn = false;
int val=0;

void setup()
{
pinMode (switchPin, INPUT);
pinMode (ledPin, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}

boolean debounce(boolean last)
{
  boolean cur=digitalRead(switchPin);
  if (last!=cur)
  {
    delay(5);
    cur = digitalRead(switchPin);
  }
  return cur;
    }

  void loop()
  {
      curBut=debounce (lastBut);
      if (lastBut == LOW && curBut == HIGH)
      {
   ledOn =!ledOn;
  }
   lastBut = curBut; 
   digitalWrite(ledPin,ledOn);
  if (ledOn == HIGH)
  {
   Serial.println("H"); 
  }
  else
  {
  Serial.println("L");
  }
delay(100);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Кусок кода программы запуска генератора. Две кнопки. При нажании на одну и удержании delayBefore (3000 мсек) срабатывает запуск.

```
void setup() {
  ......
  previousTime = millis();
  ....
}

void loop() {  
  Serial.println(getEngineTemp());
  byte buttonState = digitalRead(pinButtonStart)+2*digitalRead(pinButtonStop);
  switch (buttonState) {
    case 1:{
      if (!getEngineStatus()){
        if (millis()-previousTime > delayBefore) {
          StartEngine();
          }
      }
      break;
    }
    case 2: if (getEngineStatus()) { StopEngine();}
    default: {previousTime = millis();}
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Используй тиковую систему.

В главном лупе считай количество определённых отрезков времени (например, 10 милисекунд), и по истечении этих 10 милисекунд инкриментируй некую переменную. Тогда ты сможешь узнать сколько времени кнопка была нажата.